# Mostrar el ID en Textbox C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Compañeros estoy desarrollando un proyecto en ASP.NET C#, el problema es que quiero mostrar el ID en un textbox de mi formulario, que vaya aumentando de uno en uno, estoy haciendo altas,bajas,cambios, por ejemplo que al agregar un nuevo registro muestre en el textbox el ID pero que aumente para poder darlo de alta en mi Data Base SQL. No se si me explique.

Comment: Está muy abierta tu pregunta y no se entiende lo que preguntas, recomiendo que especifiques y dividas tu pregunta para que esté más clara.

Comment: Actualice mi pregunta

Comment: el id puede ser cualquiera, es un autoincrement en la BD, es llave o no???

Comment: @Alberto Rojas--Asi es es mi llave primaria y es autoincrementable, quiero que sea asi como en mi data base.

Comment: ya intentaste consultar el ultimo registro insertado y al mostrarlo en el textbox sumarle 1? deberías poner código de lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada cuanto queres que aumente ese ID?, cada vez que el usuario carga ese formulario?, o cada vez que el usuario toca algún botón?. Si tu ID es Autoincremental cada vez que el usuario ejecute uno de los dos eventos mencionados anteriormente deberías insertar datos para que aumente la primery key y luego en la BD tener un procedimiento almacenado para traer el ultimo ID

```
SELECT TOP(1) ID
FROM "Nombre Tabla"
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

Comment: Quiero que aumente cada que se haga una alta.

Comment: Cada vez que hagas el alta e insertes un registro se va a aumentar automáticamente, luego para traer el valor del ultimo ID tenes que usar la query que puse @MarthA.

Comment: Muy bien, cómo puedo agregar ese procedimiento en mi proyecto para que lo haga?

Comment: @MarthA. Si ejecutas lo que puse en la base de datos vas a ver que te trae el ultimo ID, para agregarlo como procedimiento almacenado tenes que poner antes CREATE PROCEDURE UltimoID AS. Despues lo llamas desde tu proyecto